# express-jwt-authz and typescript

Tags: typescript, auth0

I'm new to all of these nodejs, typescript, auth0.

i get this error, when i try to use express-jwt-authz in one sample app:

src/server.ts:4:22 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express-jwt-authz'. 'C:/Code/Nodejs_practice/nodeHttp/node_modules/express-jwt-authz/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/express-jwt-authz` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express-jwt-authz';`

4 import jwtAuthz from 'express-jwt-authz';

is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Did you try running `npm install @types/express-jwt-authz --save-dev`?

Comment: yes, but that didnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that module that doesn't have typings, you can use via:

```js
const jwtAuthz = require("express-jwt-authz");
```

Comment: Thanks, this is how i'm doing already and passed the step. Looks like this is the only option, marked your answer as final.